# Criteria for a working basalt generator

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am wondering about the criteria that can make a working basalt generator. I know that this configuration works:

```
Key:
L = Lava source block      l = Flowing Lava      B = Blue ice       S = Soul Soil     X = Choice block
```

```
        B
L l l l
        S
```

However, I am wondering if this configuration works, because I am hoping to put a hopper underneath to collect mined basalt:

```
        B
L l l l   S
        X
```

If it doesn't work, is there another way to collect dropped basalt, other than manually picking it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The soul soil *must* be below the flowing lava. But there is a way!

Try this:
[image: Test]
The item below the soul soil is a Rail with a Minecart with Hopper on top of it. These beauties are able to suck up items above the soul soil!

(Obviously you'll need to protect the area to stop the basalt flying everywhere!)

Now I've added an extra feature: a piston that you can use to shut-off the system by activating it. This is in case you accidentally pick up an item - you can shut it off and throw it on the soul soil to funnel it in.

Comment: Yes, I know that we can use hopper minecarts, but I'd prefer not to because I don't want to go too iron-intensive.